# Sharepoint calendar event attendees

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar

I want to programmatically add an event to a calendar in SharePoint 2010. I get the list of events and add element to this list.

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(sCalendarName);
if (list != null)
{
   SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
   item["Title"] = "New Event";
   item["Description"] = "New Event created using SharePoint Object Model";
   item["Location"] = "First Floor";
   item["EventDate"] = DateTime.Now;
   item["EndDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
   item["Category"] = "Business";
   item["fAllDayEvent"] = false;
   item["Author"] = web.EnsureUser(@"domen\username");
   item.Update();
}
```

But I can't find how to add a value to the "Particiants" ("Attendee") field.
If you look throw the `item.Xml` there is ows_ParticipantsPicker element, which contains users, that added by Sharepoint Calendar interface.

How can I add a participant (Attendee) to the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using SPFieldUserValueCollection as the value of field?

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection values = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(@"domen\username");
values.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name));      
item["Participants"] = values;
```

Also, don't use SPList.Items.Add(), it gets all items before adding a new one. Use SPList.AddItem().